# Is git best practice to version a top-level directory?

Tags: git

If I create a git repository, is it best to have a single top directory (with the project name)

```
root
|- project
   |- foo.c
   |- baz.S
|- readme.md
```

or is it better to version the contents of a top directory at the root?

```
root
|- foo.c
|- baz.S
|- readme.md
```

Or does it not matter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "top directory"? You should strive to keep one project = one repository, other than that I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tried to clarify the question. It could be important to know beforehand if there is a directory at the root or if the files are there directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common approach is to have the root of your repository be the root of your project

```
root
|- file1
|- file2
```

But in some cases it would make sense to wrap your project files in another directory to separate them from meta/config files. For example if you were working on a web page:

```
root
|- project
   |- index.html
   |- script.js
|- readme.md
```

It just comes down to your own preferences and requirements. Whatever looks right.